# GVim for Windows Increasing number by one

Tags: windows, vim

In the Vim documents there a mention that Crtl+A should increase a number by one. In the Windows version it instead selects all text.

Is there an alternative shortcut for increasing a number by one?

Comment: You should consider disabling that stupid `mswin.vim` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the following in my vimrc:

```
nnoremap <kPlus> <C-a>
nnoremap <kMinus> <C-x>
```

This maps increment and decrement to the keypad + and - keys.